# Android fragment not shown if orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

In my application I've many fragments that can be displayed in portrait and landscape mode, except for one, that I need to be displayed in portrait mode.

Now things works quite well, except for one case:
If the phone is on landscape mode, and I want to display the fragment that is configured to be portrait, the screen became blank and nothing appears until I change the orientation.

There is a way to show my activity in portrait even when the phone is in "landscape position".

This is how I set the fragment to be portrait only when displayed, and revert back to original configuration when the changing to other fragments.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "resume");
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onpause");
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
}
```

P.s. All the fragments are in the same activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for all the answers, anyway i found another solution, just one line to change.

Apparently the problem happens only if i try to change the orientation from inside the fragment that i want in portrait (the screen goes blank)

But if i change set the  orientation, from the caller fragment, it is correctly changed.

So what i did, is:

in the MainMenu fragment just before the call to the Portrait Fragment  mode i change the orientation:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

(obviously in the other fragment i revert to ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR when onPause is called).

Answer (score 2):

I had some similar issue and in my activity I tried something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Fragment currentFragment =
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .detach(currentFragment).attach(currentFragment).commit();
}
```

and also added this to `AndroidManifest.xml` file `<activity>`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onSaveInstanceState to store and retrieve your fragment tag names. And based on fragment tag name you load fragment

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            currentView = savedInstanceState.getString(TAB_STATE, null);
        }

        if (currentView != null) {
            if ("Your_Fragment_Tag_name".equals(currentView)) {
                switchFragment(feedFragment, "Your_Fragment_Tag_name");
            }
        } else {
            switchFragment(feedFragment, "Your_Fragment_Tag_name");
        }
      }


        @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString(TAB_STATE, currentView);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    /**
     * to switchFragment
     *
     * @param fragment Fragment
     * @param view     String
     */
    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, String view) {
        int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackCount; i++) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(view);
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(currentFragment);
        } else {
            currentView = view;
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, view);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the fragment that you want to force the Activity to be in the portrait mode, you can use:

`getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

and switch back to

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);`

or whatever is your desired orientation state when replacing it with another fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

> android:screenOrientation="portrait"

in the activity tag in Manifest File to fix the orientation of any activity.

Comment: But this is not what i want! I want that all other fragments can change orientation, except one that has to be fixed in portrait!

Comment: that one fragment is in same activity where all others are

Comment: @PreetikaKaur lvan just want one fragment to not to change its orientation is this possible with that attribute ?

Comment: He did not mention that the one fragment that he want is in the same activity or different activity

Comment: It is in the same activity